# Intermittent azure 403.14

Tags: azure, iis, azure-web-app-service

I have a web app in azure hosting a MVC 5 website.
Everything is fine for a week or 2 then everything stops and returns 403.14.

I'm hosted on an Azure Standard 1: medium subscription. So there should be no issues with quotas. Running .Net 4.7

If it were consistent then i could get somewhere but this is fine until it suddenly isn't. Happens at random times on any day.

Restarting the app in the admin panel doesn't work.
The only way i can get this back up is to open the web.config within the 'app service editor' add/remove a blank line then save it.

Anyone seen this issue before?

Comment: Sounds like your web app accumulates some exceptions and finally crashes ASP.NET routing. Hang dumps might help https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2017/02/02/how-to-get-a-full-memory-dump-in-azure-app-services/ but it is not trivial to analyze such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after much a fiddle.

1. I upgraded my visual studio to latest minor version.
2. installed .net framework 4.7.2
3. upgraded all projects to this
4. Added a global.asax Application_Error method and logged all unhandled errors (should have been doing this all along i know)
5. rebuilt and redeployed.

So far so good.